# Using Webform To Create Page Contnet

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to update a website that I didn't create where the entry of anonymous user submissions creates a page once approved by an admin level user. In this approval process you get the chance to review the initial submission, click add/edit submission, and then provide final approval.

**In the step "Add/edit submission" one of the field submissions from the webform submission doesn't carry over while all the rest do.**

I've done a lot of reading on this site to try and find the possible answer, but at this point I'm running out of options of how to update this.

The site uses the following Modules for the form:

- HubSpot Integration
- Webform Webform Clear
- Webform Email Reply (currently off)
- Webform Link
- Webform Rules
- Webform Tokens
- Webform Validation

The form is not using any default fields to pull over the information, nor can I see any tokens being called out that carry over the data anywhere in the WYSIWYG. Additionally, I've checked the currently made templates for incorrect field callouts to draw in the information, and nothing there seems incorrect.

**My question: Using the setup of modules above and the latest cover version of drupal how would I make sure that the anonymous user missing field submission is carried through correctly in the approval process?**

I understand that there are other ways of doing this, and I may eventually go that route, but for now I'm trying to avoid breaking the current user experience for admins to approve the process.

Thanks for the brainstorming session!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being managed by a JS Injection.